# UserDefaults.standard.string() returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I "inherited" an iOS Xcode Project in Swift. I've never programmed in Swift or used Xcode before. I copied the project from one user account to another and checked it into a git repo.

Now I'm araid this (the copying, permissions ?) might be the cause for the App not being able to read its settings properly. Because `UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "pref_Foo")` returns `nil` although in the `Settings.Bundle's` `Root.plist` there's clearly a `pref_Foo` identifier.
The App has worked before, so I don't see where this suddenly comes from.
Since I'm not too familiar with XCode all I did up til now was debug into the Application to see that `UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "pref_Foo")` is `nil`.

How could I approach this problem?
Thank you!

EDIT: This is part of my code in `ViewController.swift`

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
  loadSettings()
```

...

```
 }

func loadSettings()
{
  if(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "pref_Foo") == nil)
  { 
   printf("Error")
  }
}
```

Comment: The *userdefaults* data stores in the sandbox directory on your device or simulator, not in your code.

Comment: I thought that maybe if xcode was unable to read the plist file then it would not get compiled into the App.

Comment: Did anything happen between 10.3.2 and 10.3.3 that could have an effect on this?

Comment: By default, the sandbox path is **/Users/foo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/xxxx/data/Containers/Data/Application/xxxx**, that's kind of ***user data***.

Comment: Paste your detailed error info here, no matter what kind it is. However, the missing userdefaults won't break your build anytime.

Comment: The problem is I'm trying to read settings from the Settings.bundle. Do I have to "load" the root.plist somehow into the userdefaults?

Comment: I prefer not load it manually to user-defaults, it depends on your logic, however.

Comment: How else would you make the content of Root.plist available to your App? I'm sorry if this is a simple question, but I have never written iOS code before.

Answer (score 0):

You should use below code with validation, first delete app and install again. then use, you will get success.

```
var UserStatus:String {
    get{
        return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "pref_Foo") as? String ?? "0"
    }
    set(status){
        UserDefaults.standard.set(status, forKey: "pref_Foo")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}
```

Use of code is as below.

```
if (UserStatus ==  "pref_Foo"){
    self.logoutSuccess()
} else {
    self.loginSuccess()
}
```

Update or set value is so simple in one line code as given below.

```
        UserStatus = "pref_Foo"
```